# How to increment value by 4 of alphabetic string value in python code ? i want to print sequence like this E,I,M,Q

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ascii, python-itertools

I wan to increment value of acii_lowercase by +4 in this function.

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools

def iter_all_strings():
    for size in itertools.count(2):
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)

for s in iter_all_strings():
    print(s)

    if s == 'ad':
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Fist of all, please [fix the indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) of your code, you have mixed tabs and spaces. Then, could you add exemplary input and output? What have you tried, what does not work? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: use `chr(ord(s)+4)` where s is variable name

Comment: s=chr(ord(s)+4)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found .It take char value not string,we have string value in s. so how we do in string to char.

Comment: @divsmaheshwari in following case.. you want output like ee, ef, eg, eh. Correct? after adding 4

Comment: output series should be like this e,i,m,q,u,y,ac,ag,ak ......(you can refer column naming of Excel file.. I want to print some value in excel column so column should be like this

Comment: okay Sapan. I will wait . I stuck here in my office work.